# Mysql, how can I prevent this duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an table users like this

```
ID |     Code     | Name
1  | f965a4eb IN  | Bob
2  | f965a4eb OUT | Bob
3  | f965a4ed IN  | James
4  | f965a4ed OUT | James
```

I want to select without having the same code duplicates like this

```
ID |     Code     | Name
1  | f965a4eb IN  | Bob
3  | f965a4ed IN  | James
```

What could be the best query for this?

Comment: How do you choose between duplicates which record to select?

Comment: What is the expected result? ID 1 or 3?

Comment: Go for this: `Select * from YourTable where code like '%IN%'`

Comment: Add more sample data. Users with only one kind of code, users with multiple IN's and/or OUT's.

Comment: Your example has two different codes. One ending with 'b' and one with 'd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge with your data is the `Code`, which we would like to use to group, is buried inside a string containing `IN` or `OUT` at the end.  One approach separates out the actual code and then uses this group and get the result you want.  However, moving forward it would probably make you life easier if you maintain the isolated code in a separate column.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code, ' ', 1) AS Code, Name, MIN(ID) AS min_ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code, ' ', 1), Name
) t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Code, ' ', 1) = t2.Code AND
       t1.ID = t2.min_ID
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester